# Why does Windows 8.1 use my Hotmail address wherever my "full name" is supposed to appear?

Tags: windows-8.1, hotmail

I am signed on to my Windows 8.1 machine not as a Microsoft account but with a local account. Yet Windows 8.1 presents my email address as my "full name" to all applications that ask for it (i.e. installers etc.).

Why does it do that and how can I convince Windows 8.1 that my name is "Andrew Brehm" and not "myemailaddress@hotmail.com"?

Update: I also did a

```
$user = [LDAP]"WinNT://computername/username"
```

and then a

```
$user | Format-List *
```

but I cannot find where Windows even stores this email address it keeps using for my "full name". The .FullName field of this user is actually set to my name, but it's not used for some reason.

Comment: LDAP FullName != DisplayName. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

The email address it uses for my name is stored in the registry under

HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion

in a value named "RegisteredOwner".

This appears to be set variously to "Windows User" or my Hotmail address on all my Windows systems. For some reason my actual name, which I did type in when I installed Windows every time, was pretty much the only thing Windows didn't think belonged there. I don't know how Windows decided between my Hotmail address and "Windows User" each time.

The field can be accessed via WMI (Win32_ComputerSystem shows it as "PrimaryOwnerName") and modified in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this user is a Local user and not a Domain user:

- Right-click the Start button icon and choose **Control Panel**.
- Click **User Accounts**.
- Click **User Accounts** again (on the next page).
- Click **Manage User Accounts**.
- Select the user in question and click **Properties**.
- Edit the *Full name* field to your liking.

Comment: Control Panel has a "User Accounts and Family Safety". Clicking on that gives me "User Accounts". Then there is "Manage another account", which just allows me to click on my account. But there is no "Properties" to click anywhere I can see.

Comment: ahhhh.. crappy.  Check this MS page out and let us know if it applies/helps your scenario: [How do I change my Microsoft account name?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-8/change-microsoft-account-name)

Comment: That's about changing a Microsoft account name, not a local user.

Comment: Yes, but if you've tied you local account to a Hotmail/Live ID then it will probably reflect back once changed on-line.  As the page says "Your Microsoft account name appears on the Start screen when you sign in to Windows 8 or Windows RT."

Comment: But it doesn't. On the start screen I can see my name, not that email address. It's just installers that fill in their "Full Name" field with the email address for some reason.